# Swift converting string to double with numberformatter returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert the value of a text field, which the user enters. As users are able to enter decimal values in european number format too, I use numberformatter for that. This was what I was trying:

```
let newprice = MaximumPriceLabel.text as! String
print(newprice) -> result: Optional("10,00")
print(formatter.number(from: newprice as String)) -> result: nil
print(Double(formatter.number(from: ("10,11"))!)) -> result: 10.11 -> that is what I want
```

So there is a value stored in the variable newprice, but when formatting, it returns nil. When I test it with a manual value, it works. Is there anything I am doing wrong? Formatter.local is set to Locale.current.

**Update**: The problem seems to be that the MaximumPriceLabel.text contains not only the value I need, but really the text "Optional("10,00") - which fails when converting to a number. The value is filled like this:

```
 self.MaximumPriceLabel.text = String(describing: formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: desprice)))
```

and when I do a print afterwards, I receive "Optional("Optional(\"10,00\")")" -> even when I clear the variable MaximumPriceLabel.text first.

Comment: Unrelated but why do you cast the `text` property which is defined as `String(?)` to `String` and later once again to `String`?

Comment: Based on your comments below my answer, you need to update your question with the code that sets the `text` property of your `MaximumPriceLabel` label. It seems your label actually contains the text `Optional(...)` and of course such text isn't a valid number. So your solution is to fix the code that sets the label so the label's text only contains the number itself and not the `Optional(...)` part.

Comment: And what is this `desprice` variable? How is it declared/initialized?

Comment: When I print desprice, I get 10.0. desprice is filled by a function with a return value of type double. let desprice = getDesiredPrice(checkString: myVariables.ASIN)

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a lot for your kind help, to all of you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn how to deal with optionals.

Your first issue is how you set the label's text. Please note that `NumberFormatter string(from:)` returns an optional `String`. And never, never use `String(describing:)` to display information to a user. That should only be used for debugging.

Start by changing:

```
self.MaximumPriceLabel.text = String(describing: formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: desprice)))
```

to:

```
if let text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: desprice)) {
    MaximumPriceLabel.text = text
}
```

That will fix the issue of the label's text having the text `Optional(...)`.

Then your code for converting the label's text back to a string needs to be updated as:

```
if let newprice = MaximumPriceLabel.text {
    if let price = formatter.number(from: newprice) {
        print("The price is \(price)")
    } else {
        print("Invalid number: \(newprice)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this - and I get "Invalid number: Optional("10,00")" - and I don't understand why :(

Comment: It seems that your label actually has the text `Optional(...)` in it. Obviously such text isn't a valid number. How do you set the label's text?

Comment: This could be. It is filled by user input, from a decimal keyboard.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What code do you use to set the label's text?